Convergence of infinite composition of a piecewise linear function
I am looking into an interesting problem on the composition of piecewise linear (PL) functions.
Define a PL function as:$f(x) = m_jx + b_j \text{ if } x\in I_j$ where $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^k$ is a partition of the interval (0,1) (except a finite set of their boundaries) such that $I_j$ doesn't include its boundary, and obviously the function outputs values only within the range $(0,1)$. 
I look at the following sequence. $a_1 = f$, and inductively $a_{i+1} = f \circ a_i$. It is not hard to see that the set of discontinuity points of $a_i$ is a part of the set of discontinuity points of $a_{i+1}$, and thus it remains to ask, assuming $0<m_j,b_j<1$, can we prove that the number of discontinuity points is bounded as $i \rightarrow \infty$?
If not then what is a counter-example?

That is incorrect. a_2(x) = f(f(x)), but since f(x) is undefined on x = 0.5, then f(f(x)) is discontinuous on x = 0.5 (simply because its argument is undefined)

I guess I simply fail to understand your question.

Then take $f(x) = 2x$ everywhere but if $x = 1/2$ and undefined if $x = 1/2$. $f^n(x)$ is undeined in all points $2^{-k}$ for $k \leq n$.

The coefficient of x is a fraction (i.e. between 0 and 1), so that is not a counter example
